# MS SQL recurrence on specific date

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the query below, that gives me the patients on specific serviceid, that haven't made any serviceinterrupt = 1.

What i want to do with that is to change the dates below,

```
and incident.completionDate Between Convert(smalldatetime, '01/01/2015', 103) and Convert(smalldatetime, '21/02/2015', 103)
```

to do the following: 
The date 21/2/2015 should be today() and not specific date.
and the data 01/01/2015, should be the first day of every month from 1/1/2014 till today().

So every time i run the query, i will get the number of the patients i want, from 1/1/2014 and every 1st day of any month till today().

How can i make that recurrence (of every 1st/month) from 1/1/2014 till today()?

```
SELECT distinct patient.id, upper (city) as City
from patient
inner join ............
where 
(
    patient.id IN 
    (
            select  distinct 
            Patient.id as Patient_ID--, upper (city) as City

            from Patient
            inner join .....
            where i1.serviceId in (4,5,6,29)
            and status = 3
            and Patient.id NOT IN (
             select  i2.patientConcerned
             from Incident i2
             where 
             i2.serviceid = i1.serviceid
             AND i2.ServiceInterrupt != 0
            )
    )
    OR
    patient.id IN
    (

            Select distinct 
            patient.id as Patient_ID
            from patient 
            inner join ....
            where 
            incident.serviceId IN (4,5,6,29)
            AND incident.ServiceInterrupt != 0
            and incident.status = 3
            and incident.completionDate Between Convert(smalldatetime, '01/01/2015', 103) and Convert(smalldatetime, '21/02/2015', 103) 

    )
)

AND
patient.id NOT IN
(

        SELECT distinct patient.id as Patient_ID
        FROM dbo.IncidentCharges
        INNER JOIN ....

        WHERE 
        incident.completionDate Between Convert(smalldatetime, '01/01/2015', 103) and Convert(smalldatetime, '21/02/2015', 103) 
        and
         servicecharges.serviceid in (4,5,6,29)  
        and incident.status = 3 --completed incidents
        and ServiceCharges.chargeDescr like 'Εγγραφή/Ερωτηματολόγιο/Έρευνα%'

)
```

Comment: You are right.. I am using MS SQL.

Answer (score 0):

My answer just focuses on obtaining the dates part. You need to fill this in and use this as a block in your original query

Use a `recursive CTE` to iterate through the first day of every months starting from 01/01/2014 till the first date of the month for the current date.

```
;WITH CTE AS
    (--gets you data from 01/01/2014 till current date
    SELECT foo, bar, Convert(smalldatetime, '01/01/2014', 103) start 
    FROM dbo.IncidentCharges incident WHERE incident.completionDate Between 
    Convert(smalldatetime, '01/01/2014', 103) and Convert(smalldatetime, GETDATE(), 103)

    UNION ALL

    --gets you data from the next months start date till current date
    SELECT foo, bar, CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,start))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,start)),103) start
    FROM cte incident WHERE incident.completionDate Between 
    CONVERT(smalldatetime,DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,start))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,start)),103) and Convert(smalldatetime, GETDATE(), 103)
    and  CONVERT(smalldatetime,DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,start))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,start)),103) <= Convert(smalldatetime, GETDATE(), 103)
    )

    select * from cte
```

`getdate()` will get you the current date while `CONVERT(smalldatetime,DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,start))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,start)),103)` will get you the first day of next month. 
    The `start` column is kinda like the anchor column based on which the next "start date" is fetched.